# How to trigger on the end of an event from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook (A) that makes plausible checks triggered on the open event. Now I want to write another makro placed in another workbook (B), that opens workbook A, waits till the plausible checks are done and if everything is ok I want to sort the data and copy a subset.

Does anyone have an idea if this can be done and how? I cannot provide any code for this since I do not even have an approach.

Comment: What is the idea to check plausibility at `Open`-Event?

Comment: I have one main document where many people have access to. I generate about 30 files with subsets from this file and every time someone opens one of these subsets I have it check in the main file if the data are up to date. If not, the file is blocked. The idea is if the main file was updated but the subset file was not new created there is an old subset file. If I open this subset file now it compares itself with the main file and is not accessable since it is not updated. Now this subset file is workbook (A) in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that will fit your needs, but this is my idea:

Changes in **Workbook A**:
Move the plauibility check in WB a into a function that returns a boolean signaling if everything is okay. This function needs to be in a Module and has to be declared as `public`.

```
Function CheckPlausibility() as Boolean
    (...do your checks here)
    CheckPlausibility = True  ' Or False
End Function
```

In the Workbook-Open, call this function and react to the result ("blocking")

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If not CheckPlausibility then
       (...Disable code)
    End If
End Sub
```

In **Workbook B**:
Set `Application.EnableEvents = False` before opening Workbook A - this will prevent to execute the `Open`-code. You can call any public Sub or Function that is part of a Module via `Application.Run` (there is another way by referencing Workbook A in Workbook B, but that would glue these books together and A would be opened any time automatically when you open B).

```
const wbName = "C:\temp\A.xlsm"
Dim wb as Workbook, wbAIsOkay as Boolean 
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbName)
wbAIsOkay = Application.Run(wbName & "!CheckMe")
Application.EnableEvents = True
If wbAIsOkay Then 
   (...)
End If
```